# Google Sign-In API check for current user without button

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I can get the basic example located here to work fine: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

However, I would like to check to see if there's a user signed on without displaying the Google Sign In button.

Is there a way to check for a valid current user without providing the ability to login first?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @somedev No, per the client we went a different direction than Google sign-in...  so I basically abandoned it.  It looks like you might be able to do some server-side code though: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow